# Criar um critério de importação

Tags: python, pandas

Como eu crio regra, para que quando eu desse pd.read_excel e as colunas A e C estiverem vazias ele abortar a importação.
Preciso disso, pois o usuário ira buscar o arquivo pelo sd_principal = sg.popup_get_file('Qual o arquivo?') e essas colunas são importantes, mas elas não têm interação com as linhas de códigos, mas elas precisam estar no arquivo final que será exportado para o usuário.

**Codigo:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import PySimpleGUI as sg

try:
    sd_principal = sg.popup_get_file('Qual o arquivo?')
    output_workbook = sg.popup_get_folder('Onde quer salvar o arquivo final?')
    df1 = pd.read_excel(sd_principal)
except FileNotFoundError:
    sg.popup_ok('Arquivo não selecionado!')
except:
    sg.popup_ok('Erro inesperado')
```

Answer (score 0):

Minha solução seria criar um `df_test`, baseado nas colunas necessárias. Coloque no seu bloco try:

```
df_test = df1['A','C'] # criando o df para teste
df_test.empty
```

df.empty > se vazio True

Lembre-se! Se as colunas estiverem repletas com `NaN`, não serão consideradas como vazias `empty`, se for o caso, melhor executar um `.dropna` também:

```
df_test.dropna().empty
```

Comment: ajudou muito em outro projeto,  muito obrigado.
Mas nesse precisava tratar cada coluna individualmente, escrevi um bem feio aqui:
`# Se alguma dessas colunas etiverem vazias, sairemos do programa
if df1['Employee Number'].sum() == 0:
    sg.popup_ok('Coluna Employee Number está vazia = SAINDO DO PROGRAMA!!')
elif df1['Last Name'].sum() == 0:
    sg.popup_ok('Coluna Last Name está vazia = SAINDO DO PROGRAMA!!')
elif df1['First Name'].sum() == 0:
    exit()`
Até achar uma solução melhor.